# Why the synchronization is not happening in multithread application c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I am new to multithreading. 
When I am running the below program it is giving output as

```
Function1
Function2
1000...1001
```

but when I am debugging the program it is giving output as expected.

```
1000...1001
Function1
Function2
```

So,I think at directly running time (without debugging) mode it is getting some synchronization problem. But one thing confuses me that, I am using `mutex` then why synchronization problem is happening?

Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
void * function1(void * arg);
void * function2(void * arg);
void * function0(void * arg);
int count = 0;
const int COUNT_DONE = 10;

main()
{
  pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread0;
  pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, 0);
  pthread_create(&thread0, NULL, &function0, NULL );
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &function1, NULL );
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &function2, NULL );
  pthread_join(thread0, NULL );
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL );
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL );
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);
  return 0;
}

void *function1(void * arg)
{
  cout << "Function1\n";
}

void *function0(void *arg)
{
  int i, j;
  pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
  for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j <= 1000; j++)
    {
    }
  }
  cout << i << "..." << j << endl;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
}

void *function2(void * arg)
{
  cout << "Function2\n";
}
```

Comment: What are the empty loops for? The compiler is likely to remove them. Also, please explain how should the mutex enforce ordering

Comment: @Leeor:Mtex is used for synchronization purpose !

Comment: shouldn't you be using the mutex on `function2` and `function1` aswell?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak - only if used correctly...

Comment: @nims: now i have put mutex in both the functions as well. but thr result is same not changed

Comment: What result do you want? If you want them to run sequentially, that's easy - only use one thread.

Answer (score 1):

"*... getting some synchronization problem*" where do you see a problem?

The threads output could come in any order, as the threads are not synchronised in any case.

The mutex is used only in **one** thread.

Also

```
Function1
1000...1001 
Function2
```

might be an expectable and valid result.

As well as:

```
1000
Function1
... 
Function2
1001
```

Modifying `function1()` and `function2()` like so:

```
void *function1(void * arg)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
  cout << "Function1\n";
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
}

void *function2(void * arg)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
  cout << "Function2\n";
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
}
```

would protect the program from producing the 2nd of my example outputs.

Comment: I have applied mutex to other two functions too. but result is also not changing

Comment: You surely wouldn't get the 2nd case those. The mutex protects mixing the 3 output statments, but does not affect their order.

Comment: You might think over how and **why** the mutex shall influence the order of the 3 outputs.

Comment: Mutexes don't impart any sort of ordering. They only ensure that only one thread holding a lock on the mutex will run at the same time. Threads requesting a lock on the mutex may execute in any order. Remeber mutex is short for *mut*ual *ex*clusion.  If you need to guarantee order of execution, you'll need a more complex locking scheme, perhaps utilizing a condition variable.